# Android Studio: How to separate Run APK & Build APK

Tags: android, build, apk

When I run an APK from Android studio it generates a partial apk in the build folder. When I click on Build APK, it generates the full apk in the same folder. They overwrite each other. I need to separate the output so that if I just hit on Run, the apk will have its own "run" folder, and when I build the apk, it would not be overwritten by Run APK. If this is possible, can someone guide me through the setup? Probably a config in gradle, or in Studio itself? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app from android studio and create a build apk its the same thing so it overwrites the apk. It builds the app-debug.apk file. I think you are trying to create a app-release apk. You need to create an apk using generate signed apk for this. It will seperate the debug and release apk in two folders as debug and release.